# Which install of eclipse should I use for python development?

Tags: python, eclipse

I'm brand new to Python and Eclipse and am in the process of trying to setup my Windows 10 system with a proper dev environment.  I've been searching everywhere for a straight answer on which install of Eclipse to use for Python development but to no avail.

I've installed the Java JDK and Python but when I went to install Eclipse, I was met with over 20 options for Eclipse and none of them mention Python.  I know I have to install the Python libraries (PyDev /LiClipse) once Eclipse is setup but which option is the best to use?

Comment: A comment on why it was voted down would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is plugin based, so it really doesn't matter. All variations have different pre installed plugins.

So any [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) + [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org/download.html).

As alternative, you can also try to use PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks RvdK.  I was thinking of going with the Eclipse Standard option since it is probably lighter than the others.

Comment: @N1tr0, If light is your consideration try VSCODE